# Two solutions for CSRF on OWASP for ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: csrf, asp.net

I am confused about differences between those two solutions from OWASP [ASP.NET Web Froms Guidance](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet#ASP.NET_Web_Forms_Guidance)

Solution one:

> While viewstate isn't always appropriate for web development, using it
>   can provide CSRF mitigation. To make the ViewState protect against
>   CSRF attacks you need to set the ViewStateUserKey:
>
> ```
> protected override OnInit(EventArgs e) {
>     base.OnInit(e); 
>     ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID;
> }
> ```

Solution two:

> If you don't use Viewstate, then look to the default master page of
>   the ASP.NET Web Forms default template for a manual anti-CSRF token
>   using a double-submit cookie.
>
> ```
> private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
> private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
> private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;
> protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
>     var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
>     Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
>     if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
>     {
>        // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
>        _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
>        Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>        // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
>        _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
>        Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
>        var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
>        {
>           HttpOnly = true,
>           Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
>        };
>        if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
>        {
>           responseCookie.Secure = true;
>        }
>        Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
>     }
>     Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
> }
>
> protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     if (!IsPostBack)
>     {
>        // Set Anti-XSRF token
>        ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
>        ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>        // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
>        if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue || 
>           (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
>        {
>           throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
>        }
>     }
> }
> ```

What I didn't get is this comment about the first approach: "To make the ViewState protect against CSRF attacks you need to set the ViewStateUserKey." Looking at the code for the second solution, it clearly using ViewSate in the code, I assume the author means that "using ViewState to persist control state". So if `EnableViewState` is set to false in for the page or master page, the first approach will not work at all?

**Update:** A better comment about the second approach in [OWASP Anti CSRF Tokens ASP.NET](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Anti_CSRF_Tokens_ASP.NET)

> Since Visual Studio 2012, the anti-CSRF mechanism has been improved.
>
> The new strategy still uses the ViewState as the main entity for CSRF
>   protection but also makes use of tokens (which you can generate as
>   GUIDs) so that you can set the ViewStateUserKey to the token rather
>   than the Session ID, and then validate it against the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part for me, at least, is to construct a successful/working example CSRF attack, then it is trivial to implement both approaches and see them in working and actually mitigate the CSRF attack.

The first approach, using `ViewStateUserKey` only, seems not been affected by turn off `enableViewState`, either in page level or in web app level. As hidden ViewState is still in the rendered HTML, and the process of encoding ViewState is still in place so that you can not turn off `ViewStateUserKey` by simply turn off ViewState.

On the other hand, as the second approach is using ViewState for the storage of `AntiXsrfTokenKey`, it will stop working if the ViewState is disabled. So the comments from that OWASP page are wrong, or at least, misleading, the other comment from OWASP other page is much better and clearer.